# Android Rect not working

Tags: android, arrays, rect

I have been trying to work on a simple code for two days now. I have tried all alterations but none seems to be working.
I am trying to draw vertical rectangles with different colors.
In the first one, I am using only one Rect variable and moving the coordinates. Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
 Rect myRect1=new Rect();
 Random colorMe=new Random();
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
    myRect1.set(myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, 0, myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, myCanvas.getHeight());
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(colorMe.nextInt(255), colorMe.nextInt(255), colorMe.nextInt(255)));
    myCanvas.drawRect(myRect1, paint);
}
```

Other alteration which I tried was through an array.
Here is the code.

```
 Rect[] myRect=new Rect[5];
 Random colorMe=new Random();
for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
    myRect[j].set(myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, 0, myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, myCanvas.getHeight());
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(colorMe.nextInt(255), colorMe.nextInt(255), colorMe.nextInt(255)));
    myCanvas.drawRect(myRect[j], paint);
}
```

Can somebody please help me what is the problem actually there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing that seems obviously wrong (there might be more):

- The minimum x-coordinate of your rectangle is myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j
- The maximum x-coordinate of your rectangle is myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j

**They are both the same value, so your rectangle is degenerate.**

*Offtopic, but very relevant*: whenever you run into a problem like this, you need to break it down into smaller parts until you get it to do *something*. This will help you understand what's wrong:

1. Extract all subexpressions (like the color, and the generated x/y values) into local variables so you can easily inspect them in the debugger
2. Replace the random color by a predefined color (COLOR.YELLOW), to rule out the random element
3. Replace the caclulated rectangle by a fixed rectangle (say (10,10) - (20,20)) to rule out the coordinate calculations.
4. Replace the loop, to rule out the loop.

Comment: Seriously, I couldn't believe that was the mistake I did.
I have changed the coordinate of maximum width to *(j+1) now.

Presently, the code without array is working but the code with array is still giving problems.

It is throwing a NullPointerException at the line of myRect[j].set(....);
I have created the objects of myRect[5] and myCanvas.
Please can anyone help me again.

Is it not possible to define arrays in Rect?

Answer (score 1):

Your rect has a width of 0px. The parameters of the set() function are, in order, left/top/right/bottom. You use the same value for left and right, so the width is (right-left)=0.

Comment: Seriously, I couldn't believe that was the mistake I did.
I have changed the coordinate of maximum width to *(j+1) now.

Presently, the code without array is working but the code with array is still giving problems.

It is throwing a NullPointerException at the line of myRect[j].set(....);
I have created the objects of myRect[5] and myCanvas.
Please can anyone help me again.

Is it not possible to define arrays in Rect?

Comment: It is possible to use an array of Rect but you are using an index that lies outside of the range of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see your coordinates, first:

```
myRect1.set(myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, 0, myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, myCanvas.getHeight());
```

Top left corner has the same x coordinate as the bottom right corner, so you are drawing a rectangle with 0 width.

Comment: Seriously, I couldn't believe that was the mistake I did.
I have changed the coordinate of maximum width to *(j+1) now.

Presently, the code without array is working but the code with array is still giving problems.

It is throwing a NullPointerException at the line of myRect[j].set(....);
I have created the objects of myRect[5] and myCanvas.
Please can anyone help me again.

Is it not possible to define arrays in Rect?

Comment: You have created an array of 5 `Rect`'s, but the array only contains `null` elements. The first line inside the loop should be `myRect[j] = new Rect();`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
myRect[j] = new Rect()
```

before

```
myRect[j].set(myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, 0, myCanvas.getWidth()/5*j, myCanvas.getHeight());
```